# How to redirect the output of 'ls' (or any other shell command) to a pipe?

Tags: c++, c, bash, shell

My task is to make a program in C that opens a pipe, then one of the process' executes the ls command and writes the output into the pipe. The other process should then read it and display it in the shell.

So, the main problem I'm struggling with is this:

```
execl("/bin/ls", "/bin/ls", NULL);
```

How can I redirect the output to the pipe?

Another way I tried to do, was to redirect the output to a file, read the file and then write that to the pipe and then finally read it at the other end (and delete the file).
In a shell that would like this:

```
ls > ls_out.txt
```

But I wasn't able to reproduce that with `execl`.

Of course my favorite solution remains something like:

```
execl("/bin/ls", "bin/ls", " > my_pipe", NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) in your program.

Do the fork.

In the child process make the writing end of the pipe the new `STDOUT_FILENO`. (Read about the [`dup2`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) system call)

Execute the program you want to run.

In the parent process read from the reading end of the pipe.

This is how e.g. `popen` works under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

Use popen() instead of execl() to read the application output, see http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen

Answer (score 0):

You seem to focus on `exec()` a lot; that call is for running a process. The pipe must be set up before-hand, since the process you're going to start will just use whatever stdin/stdout already exists. See [`fork()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork), [`dup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup) and [`pipe()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) for the low-level primitives.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're looking for?

for i in `ls -1`; echo $i; done

or

ls -1 | xargs echo

?